# Value of the contour integral around an essential singularity of $1/(e^z-1) \cdot 1/(e^{1/z}-1)$.

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula, cauchy-principal-value

Let $f$ a function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},$
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(e^{\frac{1}{z}}-1)(e^z-1)}.$$
Trying to integrate this function in a closed contour around $0$ has been impossible to me. Let $\epsilon>0\in\mathbb{R}$.
$$
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}\frac{dz}{(e^{\frac{1}{z}}-1)(e^z-1)}=?
$$
The function $f$ turns out to be the same after applying a otherwise useful [contour integration around an essential singularity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3710563/622884) technique.

Is this "integrand" $f(z)=\frac{1}{(e^{\frac{1}{z}}-1)(e^z-1)}$, evaluated at some loop around its essential singularity at $z=0$, an integrable function? In case yes, How to find it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you getting these problems from? They are very interesting.

Comment: $z=0$ is not an essential singularity, since it is not an isolated singularity at all.

Comment: Hmmm: it seems (numerically) that $\oint_{|z|=1} f(z)\; dz = -\frac{13}{12} \pi i$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael (?)(...)(!)

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm glad you ask! These questions are taken from my own research.

Comment: Let $g(z) = 1/(e^z - 1), \, h(z) = g(1/z)$. Then
$$\int_{|z| = 1} g(z) h(z) dz =
\int_{|z| = 1} \left(
 g(z) h(z) - \left( g(z) + \frac 1 2 \right) \left( h(z) + \frac 1 2 \right)
 \right) dz$$
because $(g(z) + 1/2) (h(z) + 1/2)$ is an even function. Now compute the residue of $g(z)$ at zero and the residue of $h(z)$ at infinity.

Comment: @Maxim WHAT? Sorry I'm kinda slow...

Comment: The beast has fallen, see below...

Comment: @RobertIsrael Why not being an isolated singularity makes it not an essential one?

Comment: Because by [definition](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Essential_singular_point) an essential singularity is an isolated singularity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** When $\frac{1}{2\pi} < \epsilon < 2\pi$, we may use the Taylor series

$$ \frac{z}{e^z - 1} = -\frac{z}{2} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!} z^{2n}, \qquad |z| < 2\pi, $$

where $B_k$'s are the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number), to give the following Laurent expansion:

$$ \frac{1}{(e^{1/z}-1)(e^z - 1)} = \biggl( -\frac{z}{2} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!} z^{2n} \biggr)\biggl( -\frac{1}{2z} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!z^{2n}} \biggr) $$

for $\frac{1}{2\pi} < |z| < 2\pi$. So by the Residue Theorem and using $B_0 = 1$ and $B_2=\frac{1}{6}$, we get

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{(e^{1/z}-1)(e^z - 1)}
= -\frac{1}{2} \biggl( B_0 + \frac{B_2}{2!} \biggr)
= -\frac{13}{24}. $$

This indeed confirms the conjecture in the comment.

**2.** As $\epsilon > 1$ increases, it will cross the poles at $\pm 2\pi i k$. So, if $2n\pi < \epsilon < 2(n+1)\pi$, then

\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{(e^{1/z}-1)(e^z - 1)} \\
&=-\frac{13}{24}+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \biggl( \underset{z=2\pi ki}{\mathrm{Res}}\,\frac{1}{(e^{1/z}-1)(e^z - 1)} + \underset{z=-2\pi ki}{\mathrm{Res}}\,\frac{1}{(e^{1/z}-1)(e^z - 1)} \biggr) \\
&=-\frac{13}{24}+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \underbrace{\biggl( \frac{1}{e^{-i/(2\pi k)} - 1} + \frac{1}{e^{i/(2\pi k)} - 1} \biggr)}_{=-1}
= \boxed{-\frac{13}{24} - n}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice!... and for $2\pi<\epsilon$?

Comment: @DrPotato, I added a computation for that regime.

Comment: Why is $\operatorname{Res}_{z=2\pi ki}\frac{1}{(e^{1/z}-1)(e^z-1)} = \frac{1}{e^{-i/(2\pi k)}-1 }$?

Comment: @DrPotato, It relies on the following simple observation: If $g(a)\neq 0$ and $g(z)/h(z)$ has a simple pole at $a$, then $$\underset{z=a}{\mathrm{Res}}\,\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}=\frac{g(a)}{h'(a)}.$$ This is easily proved by applying the Cauchy Integration Formula to $$\int_{|z-a|=\epsilon}\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_{|z-a|=\epsilon}\frac{g(z)}{h(z)/(z-a)}\cdot\frac{1}{z-a}\,\mathrm{d}z,$$ where now $\frac{g(z)}{h(z)/(z-a)}$ extends to a holomorphic function near $z=a$ with the value $\frac{g(a)}{h'(a)}$ at $z=a$.

Comment: Awesome! Where did you get this?

Comment: I thought it was the answer, but just noticed: @SangchulLee You start showing the power series expression in terms of Bernoulli numbers. One of them is evaluated at $z$ and the other one at $w=1/z$. Both indeed, as you affirm, converge only when its argument, $z$ and $w$ respectively, is inside the open disk. However, the multiplication of both series, evaluated one in $z$ and the other in $1/z$, have radius of convergence equal to $0$ in the $z$-complex plane, thus the remaining part of the argument is not valid.

Comment: @DrPotato, Both of the Laurent series $$ \frac{z}{e^z-1} = -\frac{z}{2} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!} z^{2n} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \frac{1/z}{e^{1/z}-1} = -\frac{1}{2z} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!z^{2n}} $$ converge absolutely over the annulus $\frac{1}{2\pi}<|z|<2\pi$. So, not only one may freely rearrange the order of the terms in the double sum arising from the product, but also can distribute the integral symbol term-wise (thanks to the locally uniform convergence of the resulting double sum).

Comment: @DrPotato, In case you have not been exposed to the topic of Laurent series, here is a very brief idea about what it is: A holomorphic function $f$ over an annulus $r<|z-z_0|<R$ may be expanded as a Laurent series: $$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n.$$ The theory of Laurent series has many parallels to that of power series, which makes it extremely useful. (You may also check [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) about this.)